# issue with converting keras h5 model file to tflite - Type Error('keyword argument not understood: ', 'interpolation')

Tags: keras, tensorflow-lite

Built my own model in keras (only modified existing VGGSegnet version) which works perfectly. Trained Model with keras in google colab
Then downloaded ex1.model.1 to my laptop
(Inference works great on laptop)
Converted the model to a h5 file using:

```
from keras.models import load_model, save_model
m = load_model('ex1.model.1')
m.save('model.h5')
```

Because I wanted to convert the model to the tflite using the terminal command from tflites for keras models [website](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/cmdline_examples):
 tflite_convert --output_file=newmode.tflite --keras_model_file=model.h5

gives me this error

```
    Instructions for updating:
`normal` is a deprecated alias for `truncated_normal`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/otto/miniconda3/bin/tflite_convert", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/otto/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 412, in main
    app.run(main=run_main, argv=sys.argv[:1])
  File "/home/otto/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/otto/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 408, in run_main
    _convert_model(tflite_flags)
  File "/home/otto/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 100, in _convert_model
    converter = _get_toco_converter(flags)
  File "/home/otto/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 87, in _get_toco_converter
    return converter_fn(**converter_kwargs)
  File "/home/otto/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/lite.py", line 368, in from_keras_model_file
    keras_model = _keras.models.load_model(model_file)
  File "/home/otto/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/saving.py", line 230, in load_model
    model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/otto/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/saving.py", line 310, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/otto/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 64, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/otto/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 173, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/home/otto/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 1292, in from_config
    process_layer(layer_data)
  File "/home/otto/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 1278, in process_layer
    layer = deserialize_layer(layer_data, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/otto/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 64, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/otto/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 175, in deserialize_keras_object
    return cls.from_config(config['config'])
  File "/home/otto/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1606, in from_config
    return cls(**config)
  File "/home/otto/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 1896, in __init__
    super(UpSampling2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/home/otto/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpointable/base.py", line 474, in _method_wrapper
    method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/otto/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 138, in __init__
    raise TypeError('Keyword argument not understood:', kwarg)
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'interpolation')
```

Google Colab was using keras version 2.2.4 and tensorflow 1.12.0 (and python2)
My Laptop used Linux 18.10,  and same keras/ tensorflow versions (and python 3.5)

Any Ideas? Thanks for your help!

edit: checked whether training and running on local machine makes any difference - but still same error
Should I provide the train.py and model file?

Comment: Are you using Windows or MacOS or Linux?

Comment: Linux Ubuntu - as stated above

Answer (score 0):

Using tflite_convert command tool gives a ton of errors. If you wish to convert your keras model (.h5) to TensorFlow Lite format (.tflite), then you can do it with Google Colab. Follow these steps:

1. Create a Google Colab Notebook. In the left top corner, click the "UPLOAD" button and upload your .h5 file.
2. Create a code cell and insert this code.

   ```
   from tensorflow.contrib import lite
   converter = lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file( 'model.h5' ) # Your model's name
   model = converter.convert()
   file = open( 'model.tflite' , 'wb' ) 
   file.write( model )
   ```
3. Run the cell. You will get a model.tflite file. Right click on the file and select "DOWNLOAD" option.

You can use this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IUIn9ffk5ICKujqPyuGaHL2irQ9Wmtpm) as a reference.

Comment: Tried your code but still get the same error
may the problem be caused by upsampling 2d (a inbuilt keras function) not being supported yet by lite? And if yes is there a different way of doing it? Perhaps first converting keras model to tf model ?- thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes that's true. TensorFlow Lite does support all functions of TensorFlow. Like Upsampling2d layer, even LSTM layer is not supproted.

Comment: a shame that the error message is so cryptic then - but thanks for help!